# Conditional comments like <!--[if mso]><[endif]--> are not functioning in Outlook PRE. Is there an alternative approach?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, email-templates

I'm trying to create an email with a form using HTML. As you may known, Outlook often requires special handling because of its different rendering engine.
(In fact, I haven't figured out how to create a fillable form in older versions of Outlook yet.)

While older versions of Outlook don't seem to work, I've noticed that a simple form with input fields seems to function in Outlook PRE.
Something like this:

```html
<font color="#0C3992">
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <br>
    <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" style="display: none;">
        <font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
            <font color="#0C3992">
                <font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
                    <font color="#0C3992">
                    </font>
                </font>
            </font>
        </font>
        <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/1/d/e/1FAIpQLSdvL2aeI35dJngy-q_nJfWsqS7hH4lP2h9JOM3p6d20o35uxA/formResponse"
        method="post" target="hidden_iframe">
            <font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
                <font color="#0C3992">
                    <font color="black" face="Arial" size="4">
                    </font>
                </font>
            </font>
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="190">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            <b>
                                Contact information
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="200">
                    </td>
                    <td width="210">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            Position:
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea name="entry.1151157380" required="required" style="resize:none;width:400px;height:30px;border:2; color:#0C3992; font-size:18px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:transparent;">
                            '+job_title+'
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            Industry:
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea name="entry.959426507" required="required" style="resize:none;width:400px;height:30px;border:2; color:#0C3992; font-size:18px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:transparent;">
                            '+industry+'
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            Company:
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea name="entry.479802054" required="required" style="resize:none;width:400px;height:30px;border:2; color:#0C3992; font-size:18px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:transparent;">
                            '+company+'
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            Country:
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea name="entry.1179625167" required="required" style="resize:none;width:400px;height:30px;border:2; color:#0C3992; font-size:18px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:transparent;">
                            '+country+'
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="top">
                        <font color="#0C3992">
                            Email:
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <textarea name="entry.759741514" required="required" style="resize:none;width:400px;height:30px;border:2; color:#0C3992; font-size:18px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:transparent;">
                            '+email+'
                        </textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input checked name="entry.1961118204" type="radio" value="同意">
                        Agree
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="entry.1961118204" type="radio" value="不同意">
                        Disagree
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="border:2; color:white; font-size:30px; border-color:#0C3992 ;background-color:#0C3992;"
                        type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </iframe>
</font>
```

It appears as a read-only form in Outlook and does not display in Outlook PRE.

what it looks like in Outlook

[image: what it looks like in Outlook]

I've also discovered that it's the iframe portion causing the form not to display in Outlook PRE.

So, I need to determine whether to keep the iframe portion based on whether the user is using Outlook PRE or not.
(Actually, the presence of the iframe doesn't seem to make a difference. However, there could still be other issues, so it's important to determine whether to display it based on whether the user is using Outlook PRE or not.)

However, I've encountered a problem: the commonly used  conditional code doesn't work in Outlook PRE, and I'm not sure how to determine if the user is using Outlook PRE.

I've also tried <!--[if gte mso 9]> and <!--[if mso | IE]>, but they haven't had any effect. I'm not sure how to identify tags like "mso," "IE," and similar ones for specific applications.

Can you help me figure out how to detect if a user is using Outlook PRE or suggest an alternative method for handling Outlook rendering issues?

Below are some screenshots of my experimentation results.

```html
<!--[if mso | IE]>
    <p>This is Microsoft Outlook.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <p>This is NOT Microsoft Outlook</p>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

result on Outlook PRE

[image: result on Outlook PRE]

Comment: What exactly do you mean Outlook PRE? Is that Office 365? 2019? Windows Mail? Windows/Mac?

Comment: Windows has rolled out a new Outlook named Outlook PRE.
https://insider.microsoft365.com/ja-jp/blog/new-outlook-for-windows-available-to-all-office-insiders

Comment: Seems to be "Pre" for preview -- this is the new Outlook One, based off Outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

"PRE" seems to stand for preview. So the actual name appears to be "Outlook one".

The new Outlook appears to be based on Outlook.com. So check caniemail for what works on that https://www.caniemail.com/clients/outlook/#outlook-com, and also https://www.howtotarget.email/ and run a search for Outlook.

For example, this should target Outlook.com & the new Outlook (untested in the new):

```
[class~="x_your-class-name"] {
  /* Replace this comment with your styles */
}
```

This one was labelled "Outlook PWA" so not sure how this might fair:

```
@media (display-mode: standalone) {
  [class~=""x_your-class-name""] {
    /* Replace this comment with your styles */
  }
}
```

But you shouldn't need these normally if you try and stick with what is supported. The caniemail list should help a lot for discovering alternative possibilities.